# Given two numpy arrays of same size, how to apply a function two each pair of elements at identical position?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two numpy arrays of same size and want to apply a function (here `binom_test`) to each pair of elements that are at the same position.

The following code does what I want, but I guess there exists a more elegant solution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom_test

h, w = 3, 4

x=np.random.random_integers(4,9,(h,w))
y=np.random.random_integers(4,9,(h,w))
result = np.ones((h,w))

for row in range(h):
    result[row,:] = np.array([binom_test(x[row,_], x[row,_]+y[row,_]) for _ in range(w)])

print(result)
```

Comment: Why can't you simply loop through both the arrays simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to [`stats.binom_test`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html) may be an array, but the second
argument to `stats.binom_test` must be an integer, not an array.

So unless `x+y` (the values passed as the second arguments) contains a lot of
repeated values, there is no way to reduce the number of calls to `stats.binom_test`. 
In general, you just have to call it once for each element in `x` and `x+y`.

However, NumPy does have a helper function, [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), which can make the syntax prettier. `np.vectorize` returns a function which can take arrays as input and return an array as output. `np.vectorize` is mainly ["for convenience, not for performance"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). Under the hood it performs a `for-loop` much like the one you wrote. Thus, the explicit `for-loop` can be replaced by

```
binom_test = np.vectorize(stats.binom_test)
result = binom_test(x, x+y)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
np.random.seed(2016)
h, w = 3, 4

x=np.random.random_integers(4,9,(h,w))
y=np.random.random_integers(4,9,(h,w))

result = np.ones((h,w))
for row in range(h):
    result[row,:] = np.array([stats.binom_test(x[row,_], x[row,_]+y[row,_]) 
                              for _ in range(w)])

binom_test = np.vectorize(stats.binom_test)
result2 = binom_test(x, x+y)

assert np.allclose(result, result2)
print(result2)
```

yields

```
[[ 1.          0.75390625  0.77441406  0.60723877]
 [ 1.          0.79052734  0.77441406  0.77441406]
 [ 1.          1.          1.          1.        ]]
```